# I don't think this is casting, but what is it?

Tags: c++, struct

This is enclosed in a for loop:

```
v[i] = new (&vv[i]) vertex(pts[i],i);
```

- `vertex` is a `struct`
- `pts` is a `point*`
- `v` is a `vertex**`
- `vv` is a `vertex*`

What does the `(&vv[i])` part do?

Comment: Please describe clearly

Answer (score 9):

It looks like placement new. It's the same as an ordinary `new` statement, but instead of actually allocating memory, it uses memory already available and which is pointed to by the expression inside the parentheses.

In your case it uses the memory in `vv[i]` to create the new `vertex` object, then returns a pointer to that (i.e. `&vv[i]`) and it's assigned to `v[i]`.

See e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) for more details.

Comment: Correct. Placement new is the only syntactic form which has a `(` following new. Note that "placement new" has a meaning in Standardese which is more inclusive than just "call ctor on this bit of memory".

Comment: Also, the usage of `delete` for this placement is a peculiar one. You can see it making an explicit destructor call.

Comment: @Graznarak Yes it is.

Answer (score 2):

That's [placement new-expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new).

It's constructing a new object at already allocated memory - at the address of `vv[i]`.

It's calling this [allocation function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new):

```
operator new(std::size_t, void*); 
//                        ^^^^
//                        &vv[i] is passed here
```

which simply returns the second argument. The constructor of `vertex` that matches the number of arguments of their types is then called to construct the object in place.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,it is a placement new, it sepcify a address where the new Object place in. if your (&vv[i]) equal 0xabcdef00, your new object will be in 0xabcdef00, more detial you could check c++ standard 5.3.4.

Answer (score 0):

This is placement new that allows placing an object at a specified memory location. See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/placement-new.html and [What uses are there for "placement new"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new).